# How to use external JAR files on eclipse java project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to use the jcommon, jfreechart and plotter classes by jfree on my java project to plot a few charts to compare the runnig time complexity of a few sorting methods I implemented.

The file compiles but when I try to run the tests it gives me this message:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Plotter/Plotter
    at Sorting.bubbleVsQuick(Sorting.java:230)
    at Sorting.main(Sorting.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Plotter.Plotter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 2 more"
```

I've already read a few posts here saying that you need to add the path for the JAR files via myProject => properties => java build path => libraries => add external JAR... and then specifying the path to the JAR files . But that's what I did in the first place and I haven't found any other refrences to this problem.

**--EDIT--**

I figured it out. Because it was hard finding the answer I was looking for online (even though it was a simple one) I'll share what happened for other people that might run into the same problem.

All I had to do was just go to myProject => properties => java build path => libraries => add external JAR... and then instead of using the default option in the libraries tab, I chose the sub-tab "classpath" and specified the path of the files I required. Appearently Eclipse won't do that automatically and that was the reason I couldn't access the sepcific class I needed (even though it appeared on my package explorer).

Comment: How did you try to execute your program? From inside Eclipse?

Comment: @tquadrat Yes. Also tried from cmd but it doesn't compile from there because it doesn't recognize the imported classes

Comment: Sounds like you are using Ubuntu and don't have the full jdk installed. Alternatively the program wants to load the wrong class. A minimal "working" code example (i.e. that reproduces the error) and the libs you have added would be helpful.

Comment: @Sascha I've figured out what was wrong. Eclipse automatically directs the files to the modulepath instead of the classpath, and therefore I had no access to the specific class I needed (even though it "seemed" I had access to it on the package explorer). Either way thanks for the help!